# Crashing during unlocking achievement

Tags: android, cocos2d-x, google-play-games

Once the `updateAchievement(int percentage)` function is called the game crashes as below

The game crashes with

> Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0x00000088 (code=1), thread 6584
>   (Thread-6615)

at

```
static public void updateAchievement(int percentage)
{
  if(gpgAvailable){
    Games.Achievements.unlock(((RampJump)currentContext).getGameHelper().getApiClient(), achievementIDs[currentAchievementID]);
  }
}
```

The achievements gets unlocked but the game crashes immediately.
I am struck with this error for a long time.
Please help regarding it. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Where do you initialize your Google API client? Personally, to unlock an achievement I use this:

```
public void unlockAchievement(int id)
{
    Games.Achievements.unlock(mGoogleApiClient, AchievementIDs[id]);
}
```

"mGoogleApiClient" is initialized in OnCreate like so:

```
    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
    .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
    .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
    .addApi(Plus.API).addScope(Plus.SCOPE_PLUS_LOGIN)
    .addApi(Games.API).addScope(Games.SCOPE_GAMES)
    .addApi(Drive.API).addScope(Drive.SCOPE_APPFOLDER)
.build();
```

I hope this helps :)